# How to change Phoca Gallery image pages Meta Tags?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using Phoca Gallery for Joomla 2.5 and for every image in gallery I have different page with meta tags. But for that images I only have titles. And I want to make description for those images the same as their titles.

I find out where in `Joomla` to find file that I needed to change:
/components/com_phocagallery/views/detail/view.html.php
,but I cannot find how to make changes in it.

This is code of this file:

```
<?php
/*
 * @package     Joomla.Framework
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 *
 * @component Phoca Component
 * @copyright Copyright (C) Jan Pavelka www.phoca.cz
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU General Public License version 2 or later;
 */
defined('_JEXEC') or die();
jimport( 'joomla.application.component.view');
phocagalleryimport( 'phocagallery.image.image');
phocagalleryimport( 'phocagallery.image.imagefront');
phocagalleryimport( 'phocagallery.file.filethumbnail');
phocagalleryimport( 'phocagallery.rate.rateimage');
phocagalleryimport( 'phocagallery.picasa.picasa');
phocagalleryimport( 'phocagallery.facebook.fbsystem');
phocagalleryimport( 'phocagallery.youtube.youtube');
phocagalleryimport( 'phocagallery.user.user');

class PhocaGalleryViewDetail extends JView
{

    public $tmpl;
    protected $params;

    function display($tpl = null) {

        $app                    = JFactory::getApplication();
        $document               = &JFactory::getDocument();     
        $this->params           = $app->getParams();
        $user                   = &JFactory::getUser();
        $var['slideshow']       = JRequest::getVar('phocaslideshow', 0, '', 'int');
        $var['download']        = JRequest::getVar('phocadownload', 0, '', 'int');
        $uri                    = &JFactory::getURI();
        $this->tmpl['action']   = $uri->toString();
        $path                   = PhocaGalleryPath::getPath();

        $neededAccessLevels     = PhocaGalleryAccess::getNeededAccessLevels();
        $access                 = PhocaGalleryAccess::isAccess($user->authorisedLevels(), $neededAccessLevels);


        // Information from the plugin - window is displayed after plugin action
        $get                = array();
        $get['detail']      = JRequest::getVar( 'detail', '', 'get', 'string');
        $get['buttons']     = JRequest::getVar( 'buttons', '', 'get', 'string' );
        $get['ratingimg']   = JRequest::getVar( 'ratingimg', '', 'get', 'string' );

        $this->tmpl['picasa_correct_width_l']       = (int)$this->params->get( 'large_image_width', 640 );  
        $this->tmpl['picasa_correct_height_l']      = (int)$this->params->get( 'large_image_height', 480 );
        $this->tmpl['enablecustomcss']              = $this->params->get( 'enable_custom_css', 0);
        $this->tmpl['customcss']                    = $this->params->get( 'custom_css', '');
        $this->tmpl['enable_multibox']              = $this->params->get( 'enable_multibox', 0);
        $this->tmpl['multibox_height']              = (int)$this->params->get( 'multibox_height', 560 );    
        $this->tmpl['multibox_width']               = (int)$this->params->get( 'multibox_width', 980 );
        $this->tmpl['multibox_map_height']          = (int)$this->params->get( 'multibox_map_height', 300 );    
        $this->tmpl['multibox_map_width']           = (int)$this->params->get( 'multibox_map_width', 280 );
        $this->tmpl['multibox_height_overflow']     = (int)$this->tmpl['multibox_height'] - 10;//padding
        $this->tmpl['multibox_left_bgcolor']        = $this->params->get( 'multibox_left_bgcolor', '#000000' );
        $this->tmpl['multibox_right_bgcolor']       = $this->params->get( 'multibox_right_bgcolor', '#ffffff' );
        $this->tmpl['multibox_comments_width']      = $this->params->get( 'multibox_comments_width', 300 );
        $this->tmpl['multibox_comments_height']     = $this->params->get( 'multibox_comments_height', 600 );
        $this->tmpl['multibox_thubms_box_width']    = $this->params->get( 'multibox_thubms_box_width', 300 );
        $this->tmpl['multibox_thubms_count']        = $this->params->get( 'multibox_thubms_count', 4 );
        $this->tmpl['large_image_width']            = $this->params->get( 'large_image_width', 640 );
        $this->tmpl['large_image_height']           = $this->params->get( 'large_image_height', 640 );
        $this->tmpl['multibox_fixed_cols']          = $this->params->get( 'multibox_fixed_cols', 1 );
        $this->tmpl['display_multibox']             = $this->params->get( 'display_multibox', array(1,2));

        // CSS
        JHtml::stylesheet('components/com_phocagallery/assets/phocagallery.css' );
        if ($this->tmpl['enablecustomcss'] == 1) {
            JHtml::stylesheet('components/com_phocagallery/assets/phocagallerycustom.css' );
            PhocaGalleryRenderFront::displayCustomCSS($this->tmpl['customcss']);
        }

        // Plugin information
        $this->tmpl['detailwindow'] = $this->params->get( 'detail_window', 0 );
        if (isset($get['detail']) && $get['detail'] != '') {
            $this->tmpl['detailwindow']         = $get['detail'];
        }

        // Plugin information
        $this->tmpl['detailbuttons']    = $this->params->get( 'detail_buttons', 1 );
        if (isset($get['buttons']) && $get['buttons'] != '') {
            $this->tmpl['detailbuttons'] = $get['buttons'];
        }

        // Close and Reload links (for different window types)
        $close = PhocaGalleryRenderFront::renderCloseReloadDetail($this->tmpl['detailwindow']);
        $this->tmpl['detailwindowclose']    = $close['detailwindowclose'];
        $this->tmpl['detailwindowreload']   = $close['detailwindowreload'];


        $this->tmpl['displaydescriptiondetail']     = $this->params->get( 'display_description_detail', 0 );
        $this->tmpl['displaytitleindescription']        = $this->params->get( 'display_title_description', 0 );
        $this->tmpl['descriptiondetailheight']      = $this->params->get( 'description_detail_height', 16 );
        $this->tmpl['fontsizedesc']                     = $this->params->get( 'font_size_desc', 11 );
        $this->tmpl['fontcolordesc']                    = $this->params->get( 'font_color_desc', '#333333' );
        $this->tmpl['detailwindowbackgroundcolor']  = $this->params->get( 'detail_window_background_color', '#ffffff' );
        $this->tmpl['descriptionlightboxfontcolor'] = $this->params->get( 'description_lightbox_font_color', '#ffffff' );
        $this->tmpl['descriptionlightboxbgcolor']       = $this->params->get( 'description_lightbox_bg_color', '#000000' );
        $this->tmpl['descriptionlightboxfontsize']  = $this->params->get( 'description_lightbox_font_size', 12 );
        $this->tmpl['displayratingimg']             = $this->params->get( 'display_rating_img', 0 );
        $this->tmpl['displayicondownload']          = $this->params->get( 'display_icon_download', 0 );
        $this->tmpl['externalcommentsystem']            = $this->params->get( 'external_comment_system', 0 );
        $this->tmpl['largewidth']                   = $this->params->get( 'large_image_width', 640 );
        $this->tmpl['largeheight']                  = $this->params->get( 'large_image_height', 480 );
        $this->tmpl['boxlargewidth']                    = $this->params->get( 'front_modal_box_width', 680 );
        $this->tmpl['boxlargeheight']               = $this->params->get( 'front_modal_box_height', 560 );
        $this->tmpl['slideshow_delay']              = $this->params->get( 'slideshow_delay', 3000 );
        $this->tmpl['slideshow_pause']              = $this->params->get( 'slideshow_pause', 2500 );
        $this->tmpl['slideshowrandom']              = $this->params->get( 'slideshow_random', 0 );
        $this->tmpl['slideshow_description']            = $this->params->get( 'slideshow_description', 'peekaboo' );
        $this->tmpl['gallerymetakey']               = $this->params->get( 'gallery_metakey', '' );
        $this->tmpl['gallerymetadesc']              = $this->params->get( 'gallery_metadesc', '' );
        $this->tmpl['altvalue']                     = $this->params->get( 'alt_value', 1 );
        $this->tmpl['enablecustomcss']              = $this->params->get( 'enable_custom_css', 0);
        $this->tmpl['customcss']                    = $this->params->get( 'custom_css', '');
        $this->tmpl['display_tags_links']           = $this->params->get( 'display_tags_links', 0 );
        $this->tmpl['ytb_display']                  = $this->params->get( 'ytb_display', 0 );

        $paramsFb = PhocaGalleryFbSystem::getCommentsParams($this->params->get( 'fb_comment_user_id', ''));// Facebook
        $this->tmpl['fb_comment_app_id']        = isset($paramsFb['fb_comment_app_id']) ? $paramsFb['fb_comment_app_id'] : '';
        $this->tmpl['fb_comment_width']         = isset($paramsFb['fb_comment_width']) ? $paramsFb['fb_comment_width'] : 550;
        $this->tmpl['fb_comment_lang']          = isset($paramsFb['fb_comment_lang']) ? $paramsFb['fb_comment_lang'] : 'en_US';
        $this->tmpl['fb_comment_count']         = isset($paramsFb['fb_comment_count']) ? $paramsFb['fb_comment_count'] : '';

        $oH = '';
        if ($this->tmpl['enable_multibox'] == 1) {
            $this->tmpl['fb_comment_width'] = $this->tmpl['multibox_comments_width'];
            $oH = 'overflow:hidden;';
        }


        // CSS
        JHtml::stylesheet('components/com_phocagallery/assets/phocagallery.css' );
        if ($this->tmpl['enablecustomcss'] == 1) {
            JHtml::stylesheet('components/com_phocagallery/assets/phocagallerycustom.css' );
            if ($this->tmpl['customcss'] != ''){
                $document->addCustomTag( "\n <style type=\"text/css\"> \n" 
                .$this->escape(strip_tags($this->tmpl['customcss']))
                ."\n </style> \n");

            }
        }

        //Multibox displaying
        $this->tmpl['mb_title']         = PhocaGalleryUtils::isEnabledMultiboxFeature(1);
        $this->tmpl['mb_desc']          = PhocaGalleryUtils::isEnabledMultiboxFeature(2);
        $this->tmpl['mb_uploaded_by']   = PhocaGalleryUtils::isEnabledMultiboxFeature(3);
        $this->tmpl['mb_rating']        = PhocaGalleryUtils::isEnabledMultiboxFeature(4);
        $this->tmpl['mb_maps']          = PhocaGalleryUtils::isEnabledMultiboxFeature(5);
        $this->tmpl['mb_tags']          = PhocaGalleryUtils::isEnabledMultiboxFeature(6);
        $this->tmpl['mb_comments']      = PhocaGalleryUtils::isEnabledMultiboxFeature(7);
        $this->tmpl['mb_thumbs']        = PhocaGalleryUtils::isEnabledMultiboxFeature(8);


        // No bar in Detail View
        if ($this->tmpl['detailwindow'] == 7) {

        } else {
            $document->addCustomTag( "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n" 
                ." html, body, .contentpane, #all, #main {".$oH."background:".$this->tmpl['detailwindowbackgroundcolor'].";padding:0px !important;margin:0px !important; width: 100% !important; max-width: 100% !important;} \n" 
                ." center, table {background:".$this->tmpl['detailwindowbackgroundcolor'].";} \n" 
                ." #sbox-window {background-color:#fff;padding:5px} \n"
                // gantry-fix-begin
                ."body {min-width:100%} \n"
                .".rt-container {width:100%} \n"
                // gantry-fix-end
                ." </style> \n");
        }

        // Download from the detail view which is not in the popupbox
        if ($var['download'] == 2 ){
            $this->tmpl['displayicondownload'] = 2;
        }

        // Plugin Information
        if (isset($get['ratingimg']) && $get['ratingimg'] != '') {
            $this->tmpl['displayratingimg'] = $get['ratingimg'];
        }



        // Model
        $model  = &$this->getModel();
        $item   = $model->getData();

        //Multibox Thumbnails
        $this->tmpl['mb_thumbs_data'] = '';
        if ($this->tmpl['mb_thumbs'] == 1) {
            // if we get item variable, we have rights to load the thumbnails, this is why we checking it
            if (isset($item->id) && isset($item->catid) && (int)$item->id > 0 && (int)$item->catid > 0) {
                $this->tmpl['mb_thumbs_data'] = $model->getThumbnails((int)$item->id, (int)$item->catid, (int)$item->ordering);
            }
        }

        // User Avatar
        $this->tmpl['useravatarimg']        = '';
        $this->tmpl['useravatarmiddle']     = '';
        $userAvatar                     = PhocaGalleryUser::getUserAvatar($item->userid);
        if ($userAvatar) {
            $pathAvatarAbs  = $path->avatar_abs  .'thumbs'.DS.'phoca_thumb_s_'. $userAvatar->avatar;
            $pathAvatarRel  = $path->avatar_rel . 'thumbs/phoca_thumb_s_'. $userAvatar->avatar;
            if (JFile::exists($pathAvatarAbs)){
                $sIH    = $this->params->get( 'small_image_height', 50 );
                $sIHR   = @getImageSize($pathAvatarAbs);
                if (isset($sIHR[1])) {
                    $sIH = $sIHR[1];
                }
                if ((int)$sIH > 0) {
                    $this->tmpl['useravatarmiddle'] = ((int)$sIH / 2) - 10;
                }
                $this->tmpl['useravatarimg']    = '<img src="'.JURI::base(true) . '/' . $pathAvatarRel.'?imagesid='.md5(uniqid(time())).'" alt="" />';
            }
        }



        // Access check - don't display the image if you have no access to this image (if user add own url)
        // USER RIGHT - ACCESS - - - - - - - - - - 
        $rightDisplay   = 0;
        if (!empty($item)) {
            $rightDisplay = PhocaGalleryAccess::getUserRight('accessuserid', $item->cataccessuserid, $item->cataccess, $user->authorisedLevels(), $user->get('id', 0), 0);
        }

        if ((int)$rightDisplay == 0) {

            echo $close['html'];
            //Some problem with cache - Joomla! return this message if there is no reason for do it.
            //$this->tmpl['pl']     = 'index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return='.base64_encode($uri->toString());
            //$app->redirect(JRoute::_($this->tmpl['pl'], false), JText::_('COM_PHOCAGALLERY_NOT_AUTHORISED_ACTION'));
            exit;

        }

        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

        phocagalleryimport('phocagallery.image.image');
        phocagalleryimport('phocagallery.render.renderdetailbutton'); // Javascript Slideshow buttons
        $detailButton           = new PhocaGalleryRenderDetailButton();
        if ($this->tmpl['enable_multibox'] == 1) {
            $detailButton->setType('multibox');
        }
        $item->reloadbutton     = $detailButton->getReload($item->catslug, $item->slug);
        $item->closebutton      = $detailButton->getClose($item->catslug, $item->slug);
        $item->closetext        = $detailButton->getCloseText($item->catslug, $item->slug);
        $item->nextbutton       = $detailButton->getNext((int)$item->catid, (int)$item->id, (int)$item->ordering);
        $item->nextbuttonhref   = $detailButton->getNext((int)$item->catid, (int)$item->id, (int)$item->ordering, 1);
        $item->prevbutton       = $detailButton->getPrevious((int)$item->catid, (int)$item->id, (int)$item->ordering);
        $slideshowData          = $detailButton->getJsSlideshow((int)$item->catid, (int)$item->id, (int)$var['slideshow'], $item->catslug, $item->slug);
        $item->slideshowbutton  = $slideshowData['icons'];
        $item->slideshowfiles   = $slideshowData['files'];
        $item->slideshow        = $var['slideshow'];
        $item->download         = $var['download'];

        // ALT VALUE
        $altValue   = PhocaGalleryRenderFront::getAltValue($this->tmpl['altvalue'], $item->title, $item->description, $item->metadesc);
        $item->altvalue         = $altValue;

        // Get file thumbnail or No Image
        $item->filenameno       = $item->filename;
        $item->filename         = PhocaGalleryFile::getTitleFromFile($item->filename, 1);
        $item->filesize         = PhocaGalleryFile::getFileSize($item->filenameno);
        $realImageSize  = '';
        $extImage = PhocaGalleryImage::isExtImage($item->extid);
        if ($extImage) {
            $item->extl         =   $item->extl;
            $item->exto         =   $item->exto;
            $realImageSize      = PhocaGalleryImage::getRealImageSize($item->extl, '', 1);
            $item->imagesize    = PhocaGalleryImage::getImageSize($item->exto, 1, 1);
            if ($item->extw != '') {
                $extw       = explode(',',$item->extw);
                $item->extw = $extw[0];
            }
            $correctImageRes        = PhocaGalleryPicasa::correctSizeWithRate($item->extw, $item->exth, $this->tmpl['picasa_correct_width_l'], $this->tmpl['picasa_correct_height_l']);
            $item->linkimage        = JHtml::_( 'image', $item->extl, $item->altvalue, array('width' => $correctImageRes['width'], 'height' => $correctImageRes['height'], 'class' => 'pg-detail-image'));
            $item->realimagewidth   = $correctImageRes['width'];
            $item->realimageheight  = $correctImageRes['height'];

        } else {
            $item->linkthumbnailpath    = PhocaGalleryImageFront::displayCategoryImageOrNoImage($item->filenameno, 'large');
            $item->linkimage            = JHtml::_( 'image', $item->linkthumbnailpath, $item->altvalue, array( 'class' => 'pg-detail-image'));
            $realImageSize              = PhocaGalleryImage::getRealImageSize ($item->filenameno);
            $item->imagesize            = PhocaGalleryImage::getImageSize($item->filenameno, 1);
            if (isset($realImageSize['w']) && isset($realImageSize['h'])) {
                $item->realimagewidth       = $realImageSize['w'];
                $item->realimageheight      = $realImageSize['h'];
            } else {
                $item->realimagewidth       = $this->tmpl['largewidth'];
                $item->realimageheight      = $this->tmpl['largeheight'];
            }
        }

        // Add Statistics
        $model->hit(JRequest::getVar( 'id', '', '', 'int' ));

        // R A T I N G
        // Only registered (VOTES + COMMENTS)
        $this->tmpl['notregisteredimg']     = true;
        $this->tmpl['usernameimg']      = '';
        if ($access > 0) {
            $this->tmpl['notregisteredimg']     = false;
            $this->tmpl['usernameimg']      = $user->name;
        }   

        // VOTES Statistics Img
        if ((int)$this->tmpl['displayratingimg'] == 1 || $this->tmpl['mb_rating']) {

            $this->tmpl['votescountimg']        = 0;
            $this->tmpl['votesaverageimg']  = 0;
            $this->tmpl['voteswidthimg']        = 0;
            $votesStatistics    = PhocaGalleryRateImage::getVotesStatistics((int)$item->id);
            if (!empty($votesStatistics->count)) {
                $this->tmpl['votescountimg'] = $votesStatistics->count;
            }
            if (!empty($votesStatistics->average)) {
                $this->tmpl['votesaverageimg'] = $votesStatistics->average;
                if ($this->tmpl['votesaverageimg'] > 0) {
                    $this->tmpl['votesaverageimg']  = round(((float)$this->tmpl['votesaverageimg'] / 0.5)) * 0.5;
                    $this->tmpl['voteswidthimg']        = 22 * $this->tmpl['votesaverageimg'];
                } else {
                    $this->tmpl['votesaverageimg'] = (int)0;// not float displaying
                }
            }
            if ((int)$this->tmpl['votescountimg'] > 1) {
                $this->tmpl['votestextimg'] = 'COM_PHOCAGALLERY_VOTES';
            } else {
                $this->tmpl['votestextimg'] = 'COM_PHOCAGALLERY_VOTE';
            }

            // Already rated?
            $this->tmpl['alreadyratedimg']  = PhocaGalleryRateImage::checkUserVote( (int)$item->id, (int)$user->id );
        }

        // Tags
        $this->tmpl['displaying_tags_output'] = '';
        if ($this->tmpl['display_tags_links'] == 1 || $this->tmpl['display_tags_links'] == 3 || $this->tmpl['mb_tags'])  {

            if ($this->tmpl['detailwindow'] == 7) {
                $this->tmpl['displaying_tags_output'] = PhocaGalleryTag::displayTags($item->id);
            } else {
                $this->tmpl['displaying_tags_output'] = PhocaGalleryTag::displayTags($item->id, 1);
            }
        }








        // Back button
        $this->tmpl['backbutton'] = '';
        if ($this->tmpl['detailwindow'] == 7) {
            phocagalleryimport('phocagallery.image.image');
            $formatIcon = &PhocaGalleryImage::getFormatIcon();
            $this->tmpl['backbutton'] = '<div><a href="'.JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_phocagallery&view=category&id='. $item->catslug.'&Itemid='. JRequest::getVar('Itemid', 0, '', 'int')).'"'
                .' title="'.JText::_( 'COM_PHOCAGALLERY_BACK_TO_CATEGORY' ).'">'
                . JHtml::_('image', 'components/com_phocagallery/assets/images/icon-up-images.' . $formatIcon, JText::_( 'COM_PHOCAGALLERY_BACK_TO_CATEGORY' )).'</a></div>';

        }



        // ASIGN
        $this->assignRef( 'tmpl', $this->tmpl );
        $this->assignRef( 'item', $item );
        $this->_prepareDocument($item);

        if ($this->tmpl['enable_multibox'] == 1) {

            if ($item->download > 0) {

                if ($this->tmpl['displayicondownload'] == 2) {
                    $backLink = 'index.php?option=com_phocagallery&view=category&id='. $item->catslug.'&Itemid='. JRequest::getVar('Itemid', 0, '', 'int');
                    phocagalleryimport('phocagallery.file.filedownload');
                    if (isset($item->exto) && $item->exto != '') {
                        PhocaGalleryFileDownload::download($item, $backLink, 1);
                    } else {
                        PhocaGalleryFileDownload::download($item, $backLink);
                    }
                    exit;
                } else {
                    parent::display('multibox');
                    //parent::display('download');
                }
            } else {


                if (isset($item->videocode) && $item->videocode != '' && $item->videocode != '0') {
                    $item->videocode = PhocaGalleryYoutube::displayVideo($item->videocode);
                }
                parent::display('multibox');
            }
        } else if (isset($item->videocode) && $item->videocode != ''  && $item->videocode != '0') {
            $item->videocode = PhocaGalleryYoutube::displayVideo($item->videocode);

            if ($this->tmpl['detailwindow'] != 7 && $this->tmpl['ytb_display'] == 1) {
                $document->addCustomTag( "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n" 
                    ." html, body, .contentpane, div#all, div#main, div#system-message-container {padding: 0px !important;margin: 0px !important;} \n"
                    ." div#sbox-window {background-color:#fff;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;} \n"
                    ." </style> \n");
            }

            parent::display('video');
        } else {
            parent::display('slideshowjs');
            if ($item->slideshow == 1) {
                parent::display('slideshow');
            } else if ($item->download > 0) {

                if ($this->tmpl['displayicondownload'] == 2) {
                    $backLink = 'index.php?option=com_phocagallery&view=category&id='. $item->catslug.'&Itemid='. JRequest::getVar('Itemid', 0, '', 'int');
                    phocagalleryimport('phocagallery.file.filedownload');
                    if (isset($item->exto) && $item->exto != '') {
                        PhocaGalleryFileDownload::download($item, $backLink, 1);
                    } else {
                        PhocaGalleryFileDownload::download($item, $backLink);
                    }
                    exit;
                } else {
                    parent::display('download');
                }
            } else {
                parent::display($tpl);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _prepareDocument($item) {

        $app        = JFactory::getApplication();
        $menus      = $app->getMenu();
        $pathway    = $app->getPathway();
        //$this->params     = &$app->getParams();
        $title      = null;

        $this->tmpl['gallerymetakey']       = $this->params->get( 'gallery_metakey', '' );
        $this->tmpl['gallerymetadesc']      = $this->params->get( 'gallery_metadesc', '' );

        $menu = $menus->getActive();

        if ($menu) {
            $this->params->def('page_heading', $this->params->get('page_title', $menu->title));
        } else {
            $this->params->def('page_heading', JText::_('JGLOBAL_ARTICLES'));
        }

        $title = $this->params->get('page_title', '');
        if (empty($title)) {
            $title = htmlspecialchars_decode($app->getCfg('sitename'));
        } else if ($app->getCfg('sitename_pagetitles', 0)) {
            $title = JText::sprintf('JPAGETITLE', htmlspecialchars_decode($app->getCfg('sitename')), $title);
        }
        if (isset($item->title) && $item->title != '') {
            $title = $title .' - ' .  $item->title;
        }
        $this->document->setTitle($title);

        if ($item->metadesc != '') {
            $this->document->setDescription($item->metadesc);
        } else if ($this->tmpl['gallerymetadesc'] != '') {
            $this->document->setDescription($this->tmpl['gallerymetadesc']);
        } else if ($this->params->get('menu-meta_description', '')) {
            $this->document->setDescription($this->params->get('menu-meta_description', ''));
        } 

        if ($item->metakey != '') {
            $this->document->setMetadata('keywords', $item->metakey);
        } else if ($this->tmpl['gallerymetakey'] != '') {
            $this->document->setMetadata('keywords', $this->tmpl['gallerymetakey']);
        } else if ($this->params->get('menu-meta_keywords', '')) {
            $this->document->setMetadata('keywords', $this->params->get('menu-meta_keywords', ''));
        }

        if ($app->getCfg('MetaTitle') == '1' && $this->params->get('menupage_title', '')) {
            $this->document->setMetaData('title', $this->params->get('page_title', ''));
        }

        /*if ($app->getCfg('MetaAuthor') == '1') {
            $this->document->setMetaData('author', $this->item->author);
        }

        /*$mdata = $this->item->metadata->toArray();
        foreach ($mdata as $k => $v) {
            if ($v) {
                $this->document->setMetadata($k, $v);
            }
        }*/

        // Breadcrumbs TODO (Add the whole tree)
        /*if (isset($this->category[0]->parentid)) {
            if ($this->category[0]->parentid == 1) {
            } else if ($this->category[0]->parentid > 0) {
                $pathway->addItem($this->category[0]->parenttitle, JRoute::_(PhocaDocumentationHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($this->category[0]->parentid, $this->category[0]->parentalias)));
            }
        }

        if (!empty($this->category[0]->title)) {
            $pathway->addItem($this->category[0]->title);
        }*/
    }
}
```

Where to change and what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the method: 
protected function _prepareDocument($item) (at the bottom of the listed code)

There you have title set in variable and such you can add to meta tags. You can see in this method other variables set to meta tags. So these you can use and add the title as meta tag.

For example:

```
$this->document->setDescription($title);
```